# Como limpar um input após clicar no botão?

Tags: javascript, react, input

Estou com dificuldade de achar uma solução para limpar o campos `input` após clicar no botão <kbd>calcular</kbd>.

Segue o código de forma simplificada

```
function EqBernoulli2 () {
  const [Pt, setPt] = useState('')
  const [Ps, setPs] = useState('')
  const [V, setV] = useState('')
  const [ρ, setρ] = useState('')
  const [resultado3, setResultado3] = useState()

  function calcular3 () {
    if (V == '') {
      let Prest = Math.sqrt(parseFloat((2 * (Pt - Ps)) / ρ))
      setResultado3(Prest)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='eqbernoulli'>
      <EqBernoulliM>
        <h2>Calculo: </h2>
        <p className='obs'>
          <i>Obs:</i>
        </p>
        <div className='input'>
          <label htmlfor='nome'>
            P<sub>t</sub> =
          </label>
          <input
            className='pressão1'
            type='number'
            id='pressão1'
            required='required'
            value={Pt}
            onChange={e => setPt(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='input'>
          <label htmlfor='nome'>
            P<sub>s</sub> =
          </label>
          <input
            className='velocidade1'
            type='number'
            id='velocidade1'
            required='required'
            value={Ps}
            onChange={e => setPs(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='input'>
          <label htmlfor='nome'>V =</label>
          <input
            className='altura1'
            type='number'
            id='altura1'
            required='required'
            value={V}
            onChange={e => setV(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='input'>
          <label htmlfor='nome'>ρ =</label>
          <input
            className='pressão1'
            type='number'
            id='pressão2'
            required='required'
            value={ρ}
            onChange={e => setρ(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button className='calcular2' id='calcular' onClick={calcular3}>
          Calcular
        </button>
        <div className='result' id='resultado'>
          {resultado3}
        </div>
      </EqBernoulliM>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Atualizar o estado para ficar com uma string vazia não funciona? Por exemplo, `setPt('')`. O que você tentou e qual foi o problema?

Comment: Não tentei atualizar o estado. O que eu imaginei não consegui por em prática. Sou novo na área e em certas situações me sinto um pouco travado.

Answer (score 2):

Lidar com formulários é complexo. Não é atoa que existem diversas bibliotecas para isso, como o [React Hook Form](http://react-hook-form.com), [Formik](https://formik.org), [Unform](https://unform.dev) etc.

Se você não usa uma biblioteca para lidar com o formulário, restam duas opções: [componentes controlados](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (com estado - `useState`) ou [componentes não controlados](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (com referência - `useRef`). No caso dessa pergunta, é usada a primeira opção, então explicarei apenas ela.

## Formulário com componentes controlados

Em resumo, um `input` controlado tem uma cara assim:

```
function Form() {
  const [valor, setValor] = React.useState('');
  return <input onChange={(e) => setValor(e.target.value)} value={valor} />;
}
```

Isso envolve alguns conceitos:

- **Controle do valor:** O valor do `input` é controlado pelo estado (`useState`). Se você não atualiza o estado, o valor do `input` não atualiza para o usuário.
- **Recebendo o valor:** Você recebe o valor digitado pelo usuário através do evento `onChange`, acessando a propriedade `target.value` do argumento passado como evento (no código acima, `e`).
- **Exibindo o valor:** Você passa o valor do seu estado para o `input` através da propriedade `value`. No exemplo acima, `value={valor}`.

Isso já está correto no código da pergunta. A questão é: como limpar o `input`?

Uma vez que você tenha entendido como funciona o armazenamento, recebimento e exibição do valor do `input`, espero que já saiba como limpar o `input`: basta limpar o estado. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function Form() {
  const [valor, setValor] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={(e) => setValor(e.target.value)} value={valor} />
      <button onClick={() => setValor('')} type="button">Limpar</button>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Se você possui vários `input`s, não é muito diferente do exemplo, basta limpar todos os estados:

```js
function limparInputs() {
  setInput1('');
  setInput2('');
  setInput3('');
}
```

Comment: +1 @Mpimenta no seu caso, voce poderia chamar `limparInputs` dentro de `calcular3`, logo após o o bloco `if`, mas claro, assumindo que teria um tratamento para casos de erros de valores.

Comment: Consegui fazer colocando um botão limpar chamando limparInputs